# Keep info in one place to be use in several locations

Tags: emails

As per title, what is the best practice, say if i want to save/keep info such as details of the website in one place so that when i want to change something i dont have to go thru every pages/blocks to amend it.

For example : company phone number.

Right now i have it in footer and contact page. Is there a way to change it so that every place that have the phone number will automatically change too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a best practice. I'd say it depends on the intent and what part of Drupal's CMS functions best fit your scenario. For example:

- Is it a part of distributed theme template? It could be a [theme settings](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/theme-settings).
- Is it a part of functional application logic? It could be a variable added to a site configuration form.

For most practical purposes of boilerplate phone info in a footer, I'd think most people would go for block with a region placed in the theme's footer, but Drupal is flexible by design so you could see alternative decisions depending on the intent.

Comment: Right now im thinking to create a webform for contact and save all infos in there then use which field i wanted and place it in footer or other pages.

Comment: Or create a new content type to store all the infos. 

But both i think it is kind of waste of resources since the purpose is solely to store 1 information. wont be using for anything else.

What do you think?

Comment: I think you'd find the consensus is NOT to do that; webform is used to collect _multiple_ form submissions & content types are used to group a collection of fields for _multiple_ content entries; both are overkill for a single piece of content.